# How do I access Fallout New Vegas DLC?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've downloaded Fallout New Vegas for the Xbox360 and also downloaded some DLC, but I have not seen any changes to the game and I cant seem to find out how to play it. How can I access it?

Comment: when you load your game, are you inundated with a bunch of messages?  Usually that tells you that the DLCs are loaded.

Comment: @yx. I think OP is asking about how to access the DLC from within the actual game.

Comment: You should have Radio channels relating to the different DLC you have downloaded. Tune into one of those radio stations and you should be given an objective which you follow to start that DLC.

Comment: You'll have to wander around and find the radio stations. Edit: Actually, on second thought, I think I have a mod that makes it do that.

Comment: i like downloaded fallout off xbox marketplace, then i downloaded add ons. but there is no sign that the games changed. but my xbox said sussessfully downloaded, but the game hasnt said anything

Comment: In the menu there should be an option for 'DLC' and in it there should be a list of the dlc's you downloaded. If they're not there then maybe they didn't download/install correctly

Answer (score 6):

If I recall correctly, all add-ons are loaded automatically when you start a new game or load a saved game after they are downloaded.

In order to access their content in-game, there are several different ways, one for each add-on:

- **[Dead Money](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dead_Money)**: After you step out into the Mojave Wasteland for the first time, you will receive a new radio signal on your Pip-Boy (Sierra Madre Broadcast) and a new quest (Sierra Madre Grand Opening!). Follow the quest marker to the Abandoned BoS Bunker in order to start the Dead Money quests.
- **[Honest Hearts](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Honest_Hearts)**: The crafting recipes added by the add-on are available from the start of the game (provided level and item requirements). After you step out into the Mojave, you will receive a new radio signal (Happy Trails Caravan) and a new quest (Happy Trails Expedition). Follow the quest marker to the Northern Passage and talk to Jed Masterson to begin the Honest Hearts quests.
- **[Old World Blues](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Old_World_Blues_%28add-on%29)**: After you step out into the Mojave Wasteland, a new radio signal appears on the Pip-Boy (Mysterious broadcast) and a new quest (Midnight Science Fiction Feature!). Follow the quest marker to the Mojave Drive-In between 11pm and 3am and activate the satellite to begin the Old World Blues quests.
- **[Lonesome Road](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lonesome_Road_%28add-on%29)**: After you step out into the Mojave for the first time, a new radio signal (titled only Radio Signal) appears, and a new quest (The Reunion). Follow the quest marker to the Canyon Wreckage and go into the Divide to start walking along the Lonesome Road.

Installing each of these 4 add-ons increase the max level cap in 5.

There are also two add-ons that add content, without quests, storyline or increasing the level cap:

- **[Courier's Stash](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Courier%27s_Stash)**: A compilation of the 4 pre-order bonuses that the game received. Right as you start the game, you will already have all the items.
- **[Gun Runners' Arsenal](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gun_Runners%27_Arsenal)**: Adds new unique weapons, ammunition and weapon mods, as well as a new perk ([Mad Bomber](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_Bomber)).

Besides Courier's Stash, all the add-ons add new challenges and achievements.

Comment: nothing has shown up. it says i purchased them to. would it be that i cant play them because i downloaded new vegas off the xbox market place?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue. Try starting a new game and exit Doc Mitchell's house to the wasteland, then check your Pip-Boy for quests. If it doesn't work, try redownloading the add-ons.