# DLCs for Fallout New Vegas won't start

Tags: xbox-360, fallout-new-vegas

I have the DLCs but they never start. I'm level 24. They're downloaded but but don't start and I don't have internet anymore. What can I do to start them?

Comment: Which DLC are you trying to access?

Comment: Could you be a bit more accurate about 'they don't start'? Like, did you already try to go to their entrance even without a questmarker? (Look up on the Internet where they are)

Comment: Even though I'm sure I know the answer, even though you 'have' the DLC, did you download the DLC too?

Comment: Without more information, I'd say this is a duplicate of [How do I access Fallout New Vegas DLC?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/79744/108003)